# Approaching way for Many To Many Intermediate Model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

- I would like to get your opinions is this approaching way correct?
- How can I do serializing m2m intermediate model better ?
- I would like to know how to combine `Display` and `Create` serializers..
- `models.py`

```py
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)   


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    materials = models.ManyToManyField(Material, through='MaterialProduct')


class MaterialProduct(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.FloatField(default=100)
```

- `views.py`

```py
class Products(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductDisplaySerializer(products, many=True) # Display
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProductCreateSerializer(data=request.data) # Create
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

- `serializers.py`

```py
class MaterialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Material
        fields = '__all__'


class ProductMaterialRateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    material = MaterialSerializer(read_only=True)
    material_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        write_only=True, source='material', queryset=Material.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialProduct  # attention!!!
        fields = ('material', 'material_id', 'rate')


class ProductCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''To create a product with existed material and a material rate(extra field) '''
    materials = ProductMaterialRateSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'materials')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        materials_data = validated_data.pop('materials')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for material_data in materials_data:
            MaterialProduct.objects.create(
                product=product,
                material=material_data.get('material'),
                rate=material_data.get('rate'))
        return product
```

- Displayed data:

```
 {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "product 4",
        "materials": [
            {
                "material_id": 3,
                "rate": 30
            },
            {
                "material_id": 2,
                "rate": 70
            }
        ]
    }
```

#### Creating data to send:

```
{
    "name" : "product 4",
    "materials" : [
        {
            "material_id":3,
            "rate" : 30
        }   
        ,{
            "material_id":2,
            "rate" : 70
        }

    ]
}
```

#### Returned data after creation:

- **Note: It saves data correctly but does not show like below!**

```
{
    "id": 29,
    "name": "product 4",
    "materials": [
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RetrieveAPIView` for display and `CreateAPIView` for create which is builtin features and can make things simpler and for other developers to work with your code easier because all they need to be familiar with is the way DRF works not the way you wrote the code. Basically it's better to follow patterns that other developers are familiar with.

And i don't recommend combining create and display serializers unless they are really simple. if they get a little complicated, it can get hard to debug or make changes specially if someone else is debugging your code!

And for serializing m2m, `materials = ProductMaterialRateSerializer(many=True)` is the right way and for creating you can use builtin features but if it's complicated and needs some calculation, then i recommend overriding the `save` and `update` method in your create serilizer.

and for returned data:

You can override the context like this:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ProductCreateSerializer(data=request.data) # Create
    if serializer.is_valid():

        # Get the saved object
        saved_obj = serializer.save()

        # Serialize the saved object with the preferred serializer.
        response_data = ProductDisplaySerializer(saved_obj).data

        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```